# Failing to deliminite csv-file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv-file that doesn't delimit. [Screenshot of  csv-file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IvMV.png)
This means that all the data stays in row[0], and does not divide into 6 columns. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

```
import csv

n=1048576

id=[]*n
a=[]*n
date=[]*n
b=[]*n
c=[]*n

with open('C:\\Users\\andsc\\data_1.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        id[line_count] = row[0]
        a[line_count] = row[1]
        date[line_count] = row[2]
        b[line_count] = row[3]
        c[line_count] = row[4]
        
        line_count += 1
```

Comment: Please, post sample data from your csv file as text here. Never post images of code, input, output, data, errors, etc. In this case text file opened in excel is even less helpful.

Comment: maybe the delimiter is not ","? Post the csv.

Comment: Also, not sure what you think all these lines like `a=[]*n` actually do...

Comment: The purpose of `a=[]*n` is to declare an empty array of n elements.

Comment: Yuri: I checked that it is "," by the Excel "Find"-function.

Comment: Tried to post the list as text. But my answer was deleted of some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a non-US version of Excel. In locales where the comma is used as a decimal separator, Excel expects the semicolon as the column delimiter:

```
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: That's right. I am using a Norwegian version. Tried to replace the column deliminiter by a  semicolon, but I'm still don't manage to deliminite the data.

Comment: I also get "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" for `row[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't do this:

```
id=[]*n
a=[]*n
...etc...
```

What you are trying to do is emulate a fixed-length array. That won't work. As you will see if you do this at the command prompt:

```
>>> [] * 9
[]
```

This is because the `*` *really is a multiply*, and just as `[1] * 3` gives `[1, 1, 1]` (three repetitions of the list `[1]`) doing `[] * 9` gives 9 repetitions of the empty list, which is just as empty as one repetition.

Instead create empty lists:

```
id=[]
a=[]
...etc...
```

Then, in your loop, do not index into these lists, `append()` new values to them instead:

```
id.append(row[0])
a.append(row[1])
...etc...
```

That means you don't need to keep track of `line_count`, and even if you do need to do that, use the provided method `csv_reader.line_num()`.

Using Excel screenshots to look at a CSV is often misleading. It is clear that your version of Excel expects the delimiter of the CSV to be a semicolon not a comma, which is why the data is all in one column. To be 100% sure of what is in the file, open it in a text editor like Notepad or Notepad++.  That avoids Excel's aggressive type coercion, which changes anything that looks like a date, or a hexadecimal string, into a number. And above all do not save the CSV back from Excel and assume the file still to be as expected.

It is clear that the code you presented will not run. It will get an `IndexError` the first time through the loop. You have to fix the code before it will run, and when you do that you will see that Python really does respect the comma as delimiter.

But opening the input file in Excel has given you a mistaken idea of where the problem is. You are quite right to say that comma is clearly the *intended* delimiter *in the file*. But when you open a CSV in Excel, Excel uses your *system* decimal and delimiter settings, which for European installations of Windows and MacOS are usually `,` and `;`.

Excel is not bright enough to figure out on its own that those settings are inappropriate for a given file; it needs help from you. You *can* change Excel's `File | Open` behaviour by altering your system settings, but if you change the delimiter to `,` you will have to change the decimal point to `.` (for every single application, not just Excel) and it is unlikely you would want to do that.

The workaround is to set it manually for a particular file, by *importing* the CSV instead of simply *opening* it. On the Data tab select From Text/CSV and Excel will then try to guess the settings from the first 2000 rows. If it guesses wrong you have the opportunity to fix it.

But getting *Excel to display the file* as you expect has nothing to do with *the way Python is reading it*.

Comment: Tried to write the list as text, but my answer was deleted of some reason.

Comment: Your answer got deleted because it was not *an answer to your original question.* It was supplementary info. The way to provide that is to *edit your question*, not in an answer and not in a comment. But I saw it before it was deleted, and it simply confirmed what was fairly obvious: Excel was not parsing it as expected. In my edit I gave full instructions for getting around this. But really, if you are having problems with your Python code, all this stuff about Excel is a pointless distraction.